# Jquery: Iteration through Divs and ULs and retrieve the checked

Tags: jquery, loops, each

stuck on a point with jquery.
I have to loop through several div's with the same structure and need the text inside the `<h1>` tag plus every `<li>` with the class '.checked'

```
<div id="a21315" class="content gradient">
<div class='header gradient'>
    <div class='headimg'></div>
    <h1>Input Shaft Size</h1>
    <div class="minus_sprite "></div>
    <ul class="de-radio ">
        <li id="a22134340"><span class='checked'>0.4375" X 0.88"</li>
        <li id="a22151870"><span class=''>0.500" X 1.13"</li>
        <li id="a22168545"><span class=''>0.625" X 1.50"</li>
        <li id="a22172070"><span class=''>0.625" X 1.57"</li>
        <li id="a22184915"><span class=''>0.750" X 1.57"</li>
        <li id="a22946970"><span class=''>0.875" X 1.97"</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I expect a result like this and wish to copy this in another div (#overview).

```
Text from Headline 1
-List Element with checked Class 1
-List Element with checked Class 2
-List Element with checked Class 3

Text from Headline 2
-List Element with checked Class 1
-List Element with checked Class 2
-List Element with checked Class 3
etc.
```

with this `$('.content.gradient:not(.hidden) h1').text();` I receive every Headline()
and with this line: 
`$('.content.gradient:not(.hidden) ul li.checked span').not('.hidden').text();`

I received all selected `<li>` with the .checked class. But how can I loop throught all this and can get it?

I hope I described my problem comprehensible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how can I loop throught all this

You could do:

```
var $overview = $('#overview');
$('.content.gradient:not(.hidden)').find('.header.gradient').each(function(){
    var headingText = $(this).find('h1').text();
    var $checkedItems = $(this).find('span.checked').not('.hidden');
    var checkedItemsText = '';
    $checkedItems.each(function(){
        checkedItemsText += $(this).text() + '<br/>';
    });
    $overview.append(headingText + '<br/>' + checkedItemsText );
});
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, made couple of typos - the above is now correct. Here's [a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/aAXBP/)

**EDIT 2:**

For better performance it's good to cache the `#overview` - updated the code above.

Comment: Amazing! Helps me a lot to understand how to build this loop. I try everything with .each() and children() today, but stuck totally with this. Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: Only suggestion I could make here is to also cache $(this) call... `var $this = $(this);` ... since you're making so many references to it, and thereby forcing a reparse of the DOM to get at each of those .find()s and .text().

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake of how you've written the line:

```
$('.content.gradient:not(.hidden) ul li .checked').not('.hidden').text()
```

As you don't have a checked class on your LI's, just on the spans inside, you needed a space between your li and your class-selector.

ALSO, you MUST close your SPAN tags!

```
<ul class="de-radio ">
    <li id="a22134340"><span class='checked'>0.4375" X 0.88"</span></li>
    <li id="a22151870"><span class=''>0.500" X 1.13"</span></li>
    <li id="a22168545"><span class=''>0.625" X 1.50"</span></li>
    <li id="a22172070"><span class=''>0.625" X 1.57"</span></li>
    <li id="a22184915"><span class=''>0.750" X 1.57"</span></li>
    <li id="a22946970"><span class=''>0.875" X 1.97"</span></li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, you're bound to run into parsing trouble.

EDITED: (and a jsFiddle to boot! http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/pHEhK/)

First, you really have to clean up your markup, or this will never work right. Close your divs, close your spans:

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id="a21315" class="content gradient">
        <div class='header gradient'>
            <div class='headimg'></div>
            <h1>Input Shaft Size</h1>
            <div class="minus_sprite "></div>
            <ul class="de-radio ">
                <li id="a22134340"><span class='checked'>0.4375" X 0.88"</span></li>
                <!-- snip ... see jsFiddle -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- missing a closing div -->
    <div id="a21315" class="content gradient">
        <div class='header gradient'>
            <div class='headimg'></div>
            <h1>another Headline</h1>
            <div class="minus_sprite "></div>
            <ul class="de-radio ">
                <li id="a22134341"><span class='checked'>another checked item"</span></li>
                <!-- snip ... see jsFiddle -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- you're missing a closing div tag -->
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
​
```

I added an output div to give you an example place to put your output items.

Now, for your jQuery:

```
// First, get a collection of your content blocks
var $blocks = $(".content.gradient:not(.hidden)");
// get a reference to the div you want to spit all this out into
var $out = $("#output");

// iterate through each of the non-hidden blocks
$blocks.each(function(){
    // it occurs to me that we should cache $(this) since
    // we're accessing it multiple times
    var $this = $(this);
    // get a ref to the h1 from this block's h1
    var this_h1 = $this.find(".header:not(.hidden) h1");
    // get a ref to the .checked li from this block
    var this_checked = $this.find(".header:not(.hidden) .checked");
    // if this_h1 contains a result, append it to the output div
    if(this_h1) {
        $out.append(this_h1.clone());            
    }
    // if this_checked contains a result, 
    //append that out in the output div, too        
    if(this_checked){
        $out.append(this_checked.clone());            
    }
});

​
```

I added a little style, in the jsFiddle, so you can easily see the code being output.

Comment: Pretty fast answer!
Thanks for your suggestion, I already can pick up the headline and list of a single div container, but as I tried to described above, how can I loop through several container?  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Z73Mb/2/)